# PHP i need to do this timestamp in php date function

Tags: php

I'm trying to do this timestamp in php `2019-02-01T08:21:33+0000`.

```
date("Y-m-d")
```

What do i need to add to the function date in order to create this timestamp.

Comment: Sorry. What were the input? And what is the desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating this date format in PHP: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+-HH:MM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804421/creating-this-date-format-in-php-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-hhmm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look into the docu helps: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

And the solution is:

```
date('c')
```

(with an additional colon)

Answer (score 0):

```
date('c') // c - The ISO-8601 date format.
```